# Unknown composite column name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has categories information.

The table has a field to mark the parent and child categories.

I tried to list the parent category then its child category through a query.

I tried something like

```
SELECT 
  CategoryID.categories as ParentID,
  CategoryName.categories AS ParentName, 
  parents.* 
FROM 
  categories AS parents LEFT JOIN categories AS child 
    ON child.Parent = parents.ParentID
```

but unfortunately it didn't work for me. It gives me a weird error.

```
[SQL] SELECT CategoryID.categories as ParentID, CategoryName.categories 
AS ParentName, parents.* FROM categories as parents LEFT JOIN categories as child on child.Parent = parents.ParentID

[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'CategoryID.categories' in 'field list'
```

and I'm sure that all fields name are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is, db engine reads columns [table].[column], not the other way around.  So it won't understand what CategoryID.categories is - there is no table called CategoryID.

You defined your tables as such

```
     FROM categories AS parents 
LEFT JOIN categories AS child
```

So you need to reference them using the names you gave them.  i.e.

```
SELECT
      parents.CategoryId as ParentId,
      child.CategoryId as ChildId,
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT
  parents.CategoryId AS ParentId,
  parents.CategoryName AS ParentName,
  parents.* -- < this is probably child.*
FROM
   categories AS child LEFT JOIN categories AS parents
     ON child.parent = parents.CategoryId
```

The naming convention for SQL is [table].[column]. You were using the column name first.

Answer (score 0):

Under `SELECT` you are writing `CategoryID.categories` and `CategoryName.categories`... The rule is to write it as *`alias name.field name`*.

Hence you get the error `Unknown column 'CategoryID.categories' in 'field list'`.

I suggest you try like this -

```
SELECT parent.CategoryID as ParentCategory, parent.CategoryName as ParentCatName,
     child.CategoryID as ChdCategory, child.CategoryName as ChdCatName
FROM categories AS parents LEFT JOIN categories AS child 
     ON child.Parent = parents.ParentID
```

You can also lookup here: [mysql joins with alias](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/inner-join-with-alias.php)